# Oracle function to searching in XML tag

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a table:

```
create table app_instr(
deal        NUUMBER
XML_DATA    SYS.XMLTYPE
);
```

and have following 2 rows in XML_DATA column:

```
<INSTR>
<EXTREFERENCE xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <REFERENCE REFSYSTEM="SYSTEM1" AUTOCAPTURED="false" READONLY="false">42852
    </REFERENCE>
</EXTREFERENCE>
</INSTR>

<INSTR>
<EXTREFERENCE xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <REFERENCE REFSYSTEM="SYSTEM2" AUTOCAPTURED="false" READONLY="false">42852
    </REFERENCE>
</EXTREFERENCE>
</INSTR>
```

My requirement is to extract int value 42852 only if REFERENCE REFSYSTEM="SYSTEM1". Can you please help me what oracle function to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this by running following query:

```
select x.deal,
       x.xml_data.extract('/INSTR/EXTREFERENCE/REFERENCE/text()').getStringVal()
from app_instr x 
where x.deal_no = 12334
and x.xml_data.extract('/INSTR/EXTREFERENCE/*').getStringVal() like '%SYSTEM1%';
```

Is there any better way to do it as this is giving me performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT deal,
       extract(xml_data, '//REFERENCE/text()').getstringval()
FROM app_instr
WHERE extract(xml_data, '//REFERENCE[@REFSYSTEM="SYSTEM1"]/text()') IS NOT NULL;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/766d7/14) is a fiddle